# Looking for paperback short story collection on human evolution published before 1960

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, evolution

One story in the book was about a beautiful young man who could predict the future and left a string of pregnant girlfriends to derail human evolution. The last story in the book was about a rocket ship with a male and female human to seed the next universe as ours died. I found this book on my 8th grade English teacher's bookshelf in 1960.

Comment: Aldiss's collection/fix-up novel [*Galaxies Like Grains of Sand*](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?108901) was a 1960 paperback with a human evolution theme but I don't believe it has the two stories you describe. The last story ("The Ultimate Millennia", originally "What Triumphs?" which you can read at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/Authentic_Science_Fiction_82_1957-07)), *is* about the death of our universe and the birth of a new one, but there is no "rocket ship with a male and female human".

Answer (score 2):

The first story sounds a lot like "The Golden Man" by Phillip K. Dick.  The publication timeframe is good but it does not appear to have been anthologized, only appearing in Dick's own short story collections.  I don't recognize the other story at all but maybe someone else will.  Here's the covers for the Dick collections.  https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?37578

Comment: "The Golden Man" [has been anthologized](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41364) but apparently not in a pre-1960 paperback.

Comment: I stand corrected and wondering why my check only turned up the covers that it did.

Comment: "The Golden Man" is the title of both [a novelette](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41364) and [a collection](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?37578).